# Как правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "обоего пола" или "обоих полов"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Числительное оба - собирательное. Обоих домов, обоих мужчин... Поэтому первый вариант неверен. Второй... Хорошо бы видеть предложение. Я бы, возможно, сказала - разных полов.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда бывает предпочтительнее выбрать более длинный вариант, -  например:как мужского, так и женского пола.